# Nativescript - platform specific code

Tags: nativescript

I've got an iOS specific code (class definition) and would like to include in a separate ios specific file.

So I created two files

utils2.ios.ts         <-- added my code here

utils2.android.ts

And then from another file, I did:

import utils2 = require("./utils2");

But I'm getting an error message that the module is not found.

I had to go this route because I've got a class definition in
the code and if I have just one file, I get a run-time error on Android.

Does typescript support platform specific files?

Or another option - is something like this possible in ts file

## if ios

do this

## end

Similar to C preprocesser

Comment: Add the comment `//@ts-ignore` immediately above the import statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get by with just a utils.ts file and inside it you can do platform specific logic that you mention. Your issue about the `module not found` is likely just a path issue to that module, not that the module isn't actually there. Also note that Typescript doesn't really "support" platform specific files. Nativescript takes those `.android.ts` and `.ios.ts` files and at runtime loads the file you need on the platform running. So just FYI that's not really TS related :)

Nativescript provides a `platform` module in the `tns-core-modules`. Import the `{ isAndroid }` or `{ isIOS }` from the platform module in your code and use it as the

```
if (isAndroid) { 
  // do android only here 
} else { 
  // ios 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that in the ios specific code, I'm defining an iOS specific "class" - can I define a class in a {} block construct?

Comment: Also if typescript doesn't support platform specific .ts files, then who would generate the .js files?

Comment: TS generates the .js through transpiling the source. So yes if you do `somefile.android.ts` and `somefile.ios.ts` when its transpiled you get `somefiles.android.js` and `somefile.ios.js`. NativeScript is responsible for running the correct platform file when the application runs. Sorry if my answer was confusing about this :)

Comment: Well I knew about isAndroid/isIOS but wasn't sure if I could include a platform specific class definition within an "else" clause. Looks like I can - so the problem was solved. Also, when I did somefile.android.ts, the .js file was created - but kept getting the module not found from the other file - no matter bigger picture problem solved.